# Workflow in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I have several conditions that need to be checked. If one or more conditions are true send, then the workflow sends an email.

**Example**

if B < 10000, L < 12months, revenue > BR

send an email to Owner, if not Process the opportunity

The condition in the workflow automatically grouped with AND.I want to group by OR.

How can I achieve this in CRM 2011 workflow?

Appreciate your help on this..!

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the rows you want to add to `Group OR` with the drop-down menu in the left of the row (highlighted in the image below) and then just select `Group OR` button.

[image: Selecting two rows for Group row]

Comment: I'm using CRM2011 and it doesn't let you pick anything. By default, it's grouped as AND.

Answer (score 1):

Create a check condition that has three conditions that are the opposite of your three conditions. Inside the check condition, create a "stop workflow" step with "canceled." Place your send email step at the end. If all of the three opposite conditions resolve to true, the workflow will be canceled before it sends the email.